# How can I update a specific program?

Tags: updates

I want to update only my google-chrome in ubuntu , what is the command to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable` did it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If you could accept the answer, that'd be great, thanks!